# Join only the lowest row with the nearest row from another table SQL

Tags: sql, join, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two table in Teradata like below:

Table A

```
A|B|ID|C |D
1|2|11|hh|
1|2|31|zz|ss
1|2|21|ee|nn
```

Table B

```
A|B|ID|C |D |dat
1|2|10|yy|tt|'2021-01-01'
1|2|07|tt|uu|'2021-01-01'
1|3|12|ee|oo|'2021-01-02'
```

output

```
A|B|ID|C |D
1|2|11|hh|yy
1|2|21|ee|hh
1|2|31|zz|ee
```

Explanation

The goal is to calculate column D value so, we start with rows from table A (which is a with query in fact)
for the same A and B we look for the anterior row in ID values and we get the value of C which will be the D value of current row,
Till we come to the lowest row in ID value (11 in the example) in this case we look in the table B for the max(dat) for the same A and B ( if there is multiple rows with the same max(dat) we get the row contain the max(ID) with id < id of the current row (11 in the example)

I tried (the query below) to get the result with the Lag function but I can't do the join for only the lowest id from table A with the row of table B.

```
SELECT 
a.A,
a.B,
a.ID,
a.C,
case when lag(a.A,1)over(partition by a.A,a.B order by a.id) isnot null then
lag(a.D,1)over(partition by a.A,a.B order by a.id) else b.c end as D 

from 
table_a a
left join ( select A,B,C,id,dat
from 
table_b) b
on a.A=b.A
and a.B = b.B
and a.id > b.id

qualify row_number () over(partion by b.A,b.B order by b.dat desc,b.id desc) = 1
```

Comment: Can you share how you did it? I would do a LAG over a UNION ALL of A & B.

Comment: @dnoeth yes i shred my query you can see but it didn't work fine because it join all the rows from A with therow from B

Comment: `left join ( select A,B,C,id,dat
from 
table_b) b` says in effect "all rows"

Comment: this is why i tried to correct this with qualify but it seems not working and if i put qualify in b query it will not work because  it get the max without checking the join

Answer (score 1):

Non-equi joins will have bad performance, even worse when they require row_number.

Instead of joining combine both tables using UNION ALL, then sort the data the required way and use LAG to get the previous row's value.

```
select a, b, id, c
-- find the previous NOT NULL value, prefer table_a over table_b
  ,coalesce(lag(case when x = 1 then c end ignore nulls) over (partition by A, B order by id)
           ,lag(case when x = 2 then c end ignore nulls) over (partition by A, B order by id)) as D 
from 
 ( -- combine both table into one, x indicates where a row is coming from
   select 1 as x, a, b, id, c
   from table_a
   union all
   select 2 as x, a, b, id, c
   from table_b
) as dt
-- now remove all rows from table_b
qualify x = 1
```

Comment: thanks @dnoeth it is really near, but what if the C of the previous row is null ( in table a or b), what if we have only one row of a and b columns in the table A and nothing in table B, i guess the ignore nulls will damage the result ?

Comment: I don't know which result you want. If the previous rows is null, the ignore nulls will take the previous value.